# mPDF library and float image

Tags: pdf, css-float, image, mpdf

I try to create a pdf (use [mPDF](http://mpdf.bpm1.com/)), but i have a problem.

Look at http://irk-studio.ru/files/763.pdf

The problem is float image and text.  It looks as two columns page, but it`s not good for me.

html is very simple:

```
<div class="text">Some article text</div>
<div style="float:right">
 <img src="..." />
 <img src="..." />
</div>
```

Comment: Please add fix size on page so that flot css can work.

Answer (score 4):

for floated divs do work properly in mPDF. You need to declare the div's width

see  [here](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&ved=0CEsQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pstbrasil.net%2Facibom%2Fatualizar%2Fmpdf%2Fexamples%2Fexample10_floating_and_fixed_position_elements.php&ei=lQOtUZXfFMe7Oee4gPAL&usg=AFQjCNHdqNqBfHCnlm1evpvKktbBNcEzcg&bvm=bv.47244034,d.ZWU)

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 0):

According to [MPDF's manual](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=34)

```
All Block level tags:
P, DIV, H1-H6, BLOCKQUOTE, ADDRESS, DL (contd.)

float   left|right

Partially supported as for CSS2 property.
NB Fixed-position or floating elements nested inside other fixed-position or floating elements are not supported.
```

Floating isn't completely supported as of 5.4. There is an example of how to do two columns in mPDF here: http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=246

Answer (score -1):

my solution

every floating div has the class (.fl or .fr)

```
.fl { float:left; }
.fr { float:right; }

    $(".fl").each(function(e)
    {
        $(this).css('width',$(this).outerWidth( true ));

    });
   $(".fr").each(function(e)
    {
        $(this).css('width',$(this).outerWidth( true ));

    });
```